# Fancy Correlation Plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, correlation

I'm trying to find a way to generate these pretty correlation plots in MATLAB. These are generated in R using 'corrplot' function, but couldn't find any similar code in MATLAB. Any help would be appreciated.

As a quick description, this function will create a color scale of the correlation values, and create circles in each cell of the correlation matrix/plot with the associated color. The size of the circles is also an indicator of the magnitude of the correlation, with larger circles representing a stronger relationship (positive or negative). More details could be found [here](https://justrthings.com/2016/07/24/fast-insights-with-elegant-correlation-plots-using-corrplot/).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess you'd better write a `.R` script for the plot and call it from MATLAB

Answer (score 3):

you can use [plot-corrmat](https://github.com/elayden/plot-corrmat) (or modify it, depending how articulate you are in matlab), to obtain similar visualizations of correlation matrices (top pic). Or use [Correlation circles](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45698-correlation-circles?s_tid=srchtitle) , that looks somewhat similar as well (bottom pic)...

[image]
https://github.com/elayden/plot-corrmat

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could write the below code to generate a similar graph, based on the code provided [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/496872-displaying-matrix-of-correlation-coefficients?s_tid=prof_contriblnk)

```
% Produce the input lower triangular matrix data
C = -1 + 2.*rand(12,12);
C = tril(C,-1);
C(logical(eye(size(C)))) = 1;
% Set [min,max] value of C to scale colors
clrLim = [-1,1];
% load('CorrColormap.mat') % Uncomment for custom CorrColormap
% Set the  [min,max] of diameter where 1 consumes entire grid square
diamLim = [0.1, 1];
myLabel = {'ICA','Elev','Pr','Rmax','Rmin','Srad','Wspd','Tmin','Tmax','VPD','ET_o','AW'};
% Compute center of each circle
% This assumes the x and y values were not entered in imagesc()
x = 1 : 1 : size(C,2); % x edges
y = 1 : 1 : size(C,1); % y edges
[xAll, yAll] = meshgrid(x,y);
xAll(C==0)=nan; % eliminate cordinates for zero correlations
% Set color of each rectangle
% Set color scale
cmap = jet(256);
% cmap = CorrColormap; % Uncomment for CorrColormap
Cscaled = (C - clrLim(1))/range(clrLim); % always [0:1]
colIdx = discretize(Cscaled,linspace(0,1,size(cmap,1)));
% Set size of each circle
% Scale the size between [0 1]
Cscaled = (abs(C) - 0)/1;
diamSize = Cscaled * range(diamLim) + diamLim(1);
% Create figure
fh = figure();
ax = axes(fh);
hold(ax,'on')
colormap(ax,'jet');
% colormap(CorrColormap) %Uncomment for CorrColormap
tickvalues = 1:length(C);
x = zeros(size(tickvalues));
text(x, tickvalues, myLabel, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'right');
x(:) = length(C)+1;
text(tickvalues, x, myLabel, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'right','Rotation',90);
% Create circles
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,50); % the smaller, the less memory req'd.
h = arrayfun(@(i)fill(diamSize(i)/2 * cos(theta) + xAll(i), ...
    diamSize(i)/2 * sin(theta) + yAll(i), cmap(colIdx(i),:),'LineStyle','none'),1:numel(xAll));
axis(ax,'equal')
axis(ax,'tight')
set(ax,'YDir','Reverse')
colorbar()
caxis(clrLim);
axis off
```

The exact graph is available here:
[Fancy Correlation Plots in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/699755-fancy-correlation-plots-in-matlab)